# Loop Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have to return Greg and Joe from this array of objects.

I am looping through the array and if the master is Emily I want to alert() Greg and Joe, review.name.

```js
let list = [

  {
    master: "Leo",
    review: [{
        name: 'Bob',
        stars: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Elly',
        stars: 4
      },

    ]

  },
  {
    master: "Emily",
    review: [{
        name: 'Greg',
        stars: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Joe',
        stars: 2
      },

    ]

  },

]

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i].master === 'Emily') {
    alert(list[i].review.name)
  }
}
```

It doesn't alert anything.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Strings need to be enclosed in delimiters.

Comment: You need two loops.

Comment: Using alert is certainly not what your real objective is. Explain what higher level goal is. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: What is the result you want..? Array of names?

Answer (score 1):

That is because `review` is an array of objects & you need to pass index. In this demo passing `0` to get the first object. You again loop `review` and get the name from each object

```js
let list = [

  {
    master: "Leo",
    review: [{
        name: 'Bob',
        stars: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Elly',
        stars: 4
      },

    ]

  },
  {
    master: "Emily",
    review: [{
        name: 'Greg',
        stars: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Joe',
        stars: 2
      },

    ]

  },

]

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i].master === 'Emily') {
    alert(list[i].review[0].name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`review` is an array of objects. We could one-line this like so, but I'll explain what we're doing:

```
alert(
    list.find(e => e.master === "Emily").review
    .map(e => e.name).join(', ')
)
```

`list` is an array, which has a `find` [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). In the `find` method, we pass a function that returns `true` or `false`. We can decide what we're trying to find. In this case, we're trying to find the entry where the `master` property is "Emily". Having found what we're looking for, we can use `map` to loop through the entry's `review` property, and return an array of names which we finally stick together using `join`.

Another approach would be to use 2 loops:

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].master === 'Emily') {
        let names = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < list[i].review.length; j++) {
            names.push(list[i].review[j].name);
        }
        alert(names.join(', '));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the first approach will throw an error if no entry with `master` property set to "Emily" can be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const list = [{master: "Leo",review: [{name: 'Bob',stars: 2},{name: 'Elly',stars: 4},]},{master: "Emily",review: [{name: 'Greg',stars: 3},{name: 'Joe',stars: 2},]}]

list.forEach((o, i) => {
  if (o.master === 'Emily') {
    list[i].review.forEach(u => console.log(u.name));
  }
});
```